# Errors with getting file permissions with File.Stat (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm new to programming and I am trying to figure out how to grab all the recursive directories of my array, and get the file permissions of all of them.

Googling was pointing me to [file.stat](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File/Stat.html), however the code is stating there is no such file or directory called 'stat'. For context, after getting the file permissions, my next objective is to be able to compare the permissions of the file owner to the group to determine any differences. I think part of my problem displayed with **'File::Stat:0x7f2407a9e908'** is that it's not converting to an integer.

Any suggestions on reading material or revision would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

```
%w(/etc /bin /usr/bin /usr/lbin /usr/usb /sbin /usr/sbin).each do |dir|
  Dir.glob("#{dir}/**").each do |c|
    s = File.stat("#{c}")
     puts s
  end
end
```

And here is my return:

```
#<File::Stat:0x7f2407a9e908>
test.rb:3:in `stat': No such file or directory - /usr/bin/chef-zero (Errno::ENOENT)
from test.rb:3
from test.rb:2:in `each'
from test.rb:2
from test.rb:1:in `each'
from test.rb:1
```

Comment: remove one of the `**/`, it should be enough to get all the file recursively. With it twice, you wish to ensure there's two directory under your first one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Can you go into detail about why you are doing this? In general this shouldn't be needed in Chef code. It works on a "test and repair" model, so you just write down (in this case) what you want to permissions to be and Chef will take care of checking the current values.

Comment: Hi CodeRanger, I need to do this for an inspec test to determine if files that are owned by the file owner have less privileges than 'group' or 'other'. So I need to break down all of the files in these directories and attempt to compare the file permission.